# Change caption width together with subfloat

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, subfloats

In the following code the package that give the problems is

```
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up,width=0.85\textwidth]{caption}
```

What I want to do is change `captionwidth` so that it is less wide than the normal text.
The problem comes when I want to use `subfloat` to put several pictures next to each other.
The `subcaptions` don't stay underneath the pictures, but overlay or swap or... do things they shouldn't be doing.
My question is, if there is a way to change `captionwidth`, without this problem in `subfloat`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[dutch,british]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[width=0.85\textwidth]{caption} %THIS IS THE PACKAGE WITH THE PROBLEM
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\selectlanguage{british}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
 \subfloat[fig1, not ok]{\label{fig1}\includegraphics[height=0.15\textwidth]{fig1}}\quad
 \subfloat[fig2, not ok]{\label{fig2}\includegraphics[height=0.15\textwidth]{fig2}}
  \caption{This caption is ok \cite{cursus, cd}.}
  \label{figTotal}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you should try and keep your examples minimal. For example, you don't need `babel`, `hyperref`, `url`, `amssymb`, `amsmath`, `amsthm`, nor `float` with this example. Also, you don't need to use `\cite` (since you don't supply a bibliography and it has no relevance here). More importantly, since this problem deals with widths, not supplying the figures `fig1` and `fig2` is a problem. Rather use something like `\rule{50pt}{20pt}` to create a 50pt x 20pt rectangle to "simulate" your images. Subsequently, you won't even need the `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 9):

Separate the setting for figure and subfigure captions:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[figure]{width=.85\textwidth}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0pt}
```

Comment: ...or add `margin=0pt` to the options of the `subfig` package, e.g. `\usepackage[margin=0pt]{subfig}`. This will not only fix the problem for subfigures alone, but for subtables and subwhatevers as well.